# Excel ADODB query with IMEX=0 not returning data from the first row

Tags: excel, adodb

I'm using ADODB in Excel VBA to query/update a named range in another (closed) Excel spreadsheet. SELECT queries with ADODB against a spreadsheet are simple; however, figuring out the UPDATE query was a bear. After much, much... much research and tweaking, I finally got the UPDATE to work.

However, I discovered that the SELECT query does not include the first row of data from the named range, i.e., the recordset contains 19 rows while the named range has 20 rows and the first row of the recordset contains data from the second row of the named range. The named range does not have a header row... it's solid data all the way through.

I know what you're saying, "oh, you need to set the HDR property to "No". :-)  Nope, I tried that. See below.

The only additional clue I have is that when IMEX is set to either 1 or 2, then the SELECT query returns all rows. When IMEX is set to 0, then the first row is missing. However, when IMEX is set to 1 or 2, the recordset is read-only and thus cannot be updated. As far as I can tell, the only way to make the update work is to set IMEX to 0.

For cleanliness, the code below is an excerpt from the a larger function.

strSourcePath is the full path to the target workbook
strSourceRange is the name of the range to update
avNewValues() is a two dimensional array of the new values to write to the

I'm using 32-bit Office 2016 with 64-bit Windows 10.

```
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strconnect As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim iRow As Integer, iCol As Integer

strconnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
            "Data Source=" & strSourcePath & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=No;IMEX=0"";"

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & strSourceRange & ";"

Set conn = CreateObject("adodb.connection")
conn.Open strconnect

Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs.Open strSQL, conn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

'Update the values in the recordset
rs.MoveFirst
For iRow = 1 To UBound(avNewValues, 1)
    For iCol = 1 To UBound(avNewValues, 2)
        rs.Fields(iCol - 1).Value = avNewValues(iRow, iCol)
    Next
    rs.MoveNext
Next
rs.Update
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, I have also tried IMEX=0 with the FirstRowHasNames=FALSE; this still skips the first row. And I tired IMEX=1 with ReadOnly=FALSE; this still returns a recordset that is read only (at least the error message says that it's read only.)

Comment: Are you trying to update an Excel sheet? Forget about first row issue for the time being. An update will never work, there is a limitation regarding this functionality. You are on the wrong path, I would suggest to CopyFromRecordset on a temporary sheet, make the necessary modifications, etc... etc...

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood, an UPDATE would probably work for another Excel workbook but not within the same one. Please ignore my comment above.

Comment: Thanks, @M.R. Actually, it does work. And it's fast as hell without having to open the target workbook. Using CopyFromRecordset requires opening the (large) target workbook... which means MUCH more memory consumption and CPU cycles compared to a an ADODB SQL query. Moreover, the ability to use SQL to handle the logic (as opposed to building VBA to sus out which row/column should get update) is a big value in my view... HUGE! The only issue is that I haven't yet figure out how to get the SELECT query exactly right.

Comment: Oops... @M.R.... we posted at the same time. :-)  Yes, target is in a different workbook.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following connection string for an XLSX file (note the keyword **Xml** in the string below):

```
 strconnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & strSourcePath & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=No;IMEX=0"";"
```

or this one for an XLSM file (note the keyword **Macro** in the string below):

```
 strconnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & strSourcePath & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=No;IMEX=0"";"
```

Also, try setting **IMEX=1**. I had a similar issue and this combination of parameters resolved it.

Comment: Thanks, @M.R. Good suggestions. I just tried these but both yielded the same result as before, i.e., the recordset can be updated but the first row of data is missing. When I change to to IMEX=1, then the first row of data comes back, but the recordset is read-only.

Comment: Does IMEX=2 make any difference?

Comment: Regrettably, no, @M.R. IMEX=2 behaves the same as IMEX=1, i.e., I get the first row of data but the record set is in a read-only state.

Comment: Get this... if you don't specify the IMEX property at all, then it works, i.e., all rows get returned and the recordset is read/write. Go figure.

Before I realized this, I had decided that I would just accommodate the bad behavior and add a header row to the data ranges. But now I'll just skip the IMEX property. This no doubt introduces some risk with data type mismatches, but the risk is low for the current project.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I discovered. If you don't specify the IMEX property at all, then it works, i.e., all rows get returned and the recordset is read/write. This is perplexing because all the docs I can find say that the connection objects assumes a default IMEX value of zero. If that's true, then explicitly specifying the default value changes the connection object's behavior.

Before I discovered this, I had decided that I would just accommodate the bad behavior and add a header row to the data ranges. But now I'll just skip the IMEX property altogether and except the default. This no doubt introduces some risk with data type mismatches, but the risk is low for the current project.