# How to populate data from ADODB connection with select clause

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

I have a simple Select clause that works fine and populates all the data that are in worksheet "Data" in the workbook that has been pointed to it within the GetOpenFilename. It brings over all the data except a few columns because the first cells in them are empty.

is there any way to adjust this code to ensure it captures everything?

[image]

```
 Option Explicit
Private Sub main()
Dim Path As String
 Path = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Please select the latest Report", filefilter:="Excel Files(*.xls*),*xls*")
 If Path = "False" Then End
On Error GoTo errhandler:
Dim Conn As Object, Rs As Object, Sql As String

Set Conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
With Conn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & Path & ";" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"
    .Open
     End With
 
 Sql = "SELECT T1.* FROM [Data$A1:AA150000] T1"
 
 Set Rs = Conn.Execute(Sql)
 
 Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset Rs

 Conn.Close
 Set Conn = Nothing
 Set Rs = Nothing
 End
errhandler:
If Not (Rs Is Nothing) Then
  If (Rs.State And 1) = 1 Then Rs.Close
       Set Rs = Nothing
           End If
MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ")  " & Err.Source
End Sub
```

Comment: Which columns are not recovered? In how many and which rows are the blanks at the beginning?

Comment: This is a known problem with the Excel driver. Maybe look at  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50118835/excel-adodb-query-with-imex-0-not-returning-data-from-the-first-row

Comment: Thank you all, but still does not work. tried with HDR = Yes or No, and IMEX = 0 or 1 and still does not copy the text in these columns.

Comment: @ΑΓΡΙΑΠΕΣΤΡΟΦΑ the highlighted columns in yellow in the image. and yes because the first rows in these columns are empty so it ignores them.